# LINQ: unable to use group by and sort

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ and I need to write a query that should get the grouped records order by date. My table has columns: personId, monthAccepted, amountSent, processKeyId, dateProcessed
A personId can have multiple entries. My requirement is to get the first entry(dateProcessed) for every distinct personId order by processKeyId. This is what I have tried:

```
int pageNumber = 1; 
int pageSize = 100;

var RecordsInQueue = from o in db.PersonTransaction
.OrderByDescending(o => o.processKeyId)
.GroupBy(g => g.personId)
select o;

return RecordsInQueue.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

When running the above query I am getting the following error:

> The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to
>   Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method
>   'Skip'.

How can I select the correct records using LINQ?

Comment: What type do you want to return?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to do `OrderBy` on your `RecordsInQueue`.

Although you sorted the `PersonTransaction` list to produce the `RecordsInQueue` list, you didn't actually sort that list.

You can probably just do `OrderByDescending(c => c.processKeyId)`.

The code would be:

```
int pageNumber = 1; 
int pageSize = 100;

var RecordsInQueue = from o in db.PersonTransaction
.OrderByDescending(o => o.processKeyId)
.GroupBy(g => g.personId)
select o;

return RecordsInQueue.OrderByDescending(c => c.processKeyId).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

This is just a guess as I don't know what your `ToPagedList()` method is doing. But it seems most likely that it is doing `.Skip()` to jump to the appropriate page, which it can't reliably do without knowing what order to use to skip.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
var recordInQueue = db.PersonTransaction.OrderByDescending(x => x.processKeyId)
                                        .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                                        .Take(pageSize)
                                        .GroupBy(g.PersonId)
                                        .Select(r => new {r.Key, r.Value}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query, which is not ordered, and returns unordered grouped objects. You need to order them before you call `RecordsInQueue.ToPagedList`.

Something like this:

```
var query =
    from pt in db.PersonTransaction
    group prod by pt.personId into grouping
    select new
    {
        Id = grouping.Key,
        TotalOfSomething = grouping.Sum(p => p.Something)
    };

// unordered query

var ordered = query.OrderBy( pt => pt.TotalOfSomething );

//now you can skip and take
```

Please note that in your query the result will not contain `processKeyId` since it's not in the groupby expression.